# how do I put a hyperlink on a jquery-ui tab

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using a jquery-ui tab control. On the default tab I have built a hyperlink. The href renders but the link is not clickable.
I have a function already to set the active tab.
What do I need to do to make the link active?

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                activate: function() {
                    var selectedTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
                    $("#<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>").val(selectedTab);
            },
            active: <%= hdnSelectedTab.Value %>
            });
    });
    </script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Status</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Documents</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Notes</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="label">
            <p>Current Status:</p>
            <p><dx:ASPxLabel ID="Name" CssClass="detailheading" runat="server"></dx:ASPxLabel></p>
            <p><span><dx:ASPxLabel ID="StoreName" CssClass="detailheading" runat="server"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                <a id="StoreURL" runat="server" target="_blank" >Visit Website</a>
               </span>
            </p>
```

Comment: Can't see any href in the a tag in your code

Comment: Thanks for looking Lee. It is set dynamically in the code behind.

PharmacyURL.HRef = Pharmacy.GetURL(rxDetails.StoreNumber);
PharmacyURL.Title = "Visit Website";

It shows up in the viewsource.

<a href="http://www.acompany.com/uscon" id="MainContent_PharmacyURL" target="_blank" title="Visit Website">Visit Website</a>